# How to produce a n by n matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

1. Write the following function:

   generateInput(n: number): number[][]

This function should produce an n by n array of preferences for companies or candidates. The
input generated will be used for testing a given solution. Above, we have described only the
shapes of the inputs; you will have to infer the constraints we’ve left out. Make sure that your
function always generates random values as it will be helpful to test a given solution with a
broad spectrum of input.

```js
function generateInput(n) {
  let matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      matrix[i][j] = [];
    }
  }
}
```

I'm a newbie of learning JavaScript, so could someone please check whether my code produce a n by n matrix or not?

Comment: seems like an easy thing to see. `console.log(matrix)` The question states random numbers which I do not see in the code. the way it is written you are getting 3 deep

Comment: I guess the last line should be `matrix[i][j] = Math.random();` and you have to return `matrix` at the end of the function. Otherwise looks ok to me.

Comment: Your function should `return matrix;`

Answer (score 0):

You can run this in a node environment, or in the browser console, or even in a snippet on StackOverflow.  In your case the code is failing to `return` the `matrix` when completed.  I added that line and called it with a few different values in the snippet below, so you can see what it returns.

```js
function generateInput(n){
  let matrix = [];
  for(let i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for(let j=0; j<n; ++j) {
       matrix[i][j] = [];
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

console.log(generateInput(1));
console.log(generateInput(2));
console.log(generateInput(3));
console.log(generateInput(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it produces a matrix with empty arrays. To get access to matrix variable from outside you need to return this value. See example below.

```js
function generateInput(n){
  let matrix = [];
 
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [];

    for (let j=0; j<n; j++) {
       matrix[i][j] = [];
    }
  }

  return matrix; // here 
}

const result = generateInput(5);
console.log(result);
```